# Converting date and/or time from character string in vb.net. Getting the diference of two times then update the table

Tags: sql, vb.net, datediff

Here is my code:

```
Dim time_in As DateTime = Nothing
    Dim time_out As DateTime = Nothing
    Dim totalWorkHours As String = Nothing

    getQuery = "SELECT dtr.time_in, dtr.time_out FROM dtr, worker WHERE dtr.worker_id ='" & getWorkerID & "' AND worker.worker_id ='" & getWorkerID & "' AND dtr.time_out IS NOT NULL"
    getCommand = New SqlCommand(getQuery, cn)
    cn.Open()
    getReader = getCommand.ExecuteReader

    While getReader.Read

        time_in = (getReader.Item("time_in").ToString())
        time_out = (getReader.Item("time_out").ToString())

        totalWorkHours = DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, time_in, time_out) / 3600.0

    End While

    cn.Close()
    getReader.Close()

    getQuery = "UPDATE dtr SET dtr.hours_work ='" & totalWorkHours & "' WHERE dtr.worker_id ='" & getWorkerID & "' AND dtr.date ='" & Format(Date.Today, "yyyy-MM-dd") & "'"
    getCommand = New SqlCommand(getQuery, cn)
    cn.Open()
    getReader = getCommand.ExecuteReader
    cn.Close()
    getReader.Close()
```

I'm getting an unhandled exception in updating the table. What I'm working in my code is to get the total `hours_work` by getting the difference of two times `time_in` and `time_out`.

This is my table `dtr`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dtr] (
    [worker_id]  INT      DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [time_in]    DATETIME DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [time_out]   DATETIME DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [date]       DATE     DEFAULT (NULL) NULL,
    [hours_work] DATETIME DEFAULT (NULL) NULL
);
```

Comment: What is the data type of the `time_in` and `time_out` columns in the database?  If it's not `datetime` or `datatime2`, why not?

Comment: @jmcilhinney the data type of the `time_in` and `time_out` columns in the database are `datetime`.

Comment: _I'm getting an unhandled exception_ - What is the exception message?

Comment: Try removing the `.ToString()`

Comment: @Fabio `An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll`

Comment: @StevenDoggart I still get the same exception/bug

Comment: What value are you actually trying to calculate?  It's the number of hours worked, right?  Why are you storing it in a `String` in your VB code and then a `datetime` in the database?  It's a number.  If you just want a whole number then it should be `Integer` in VB and `int` in SQL Server.  If you want a fractional value then it should be `Double` and `float`. Get your two `DateTime` values from the database, subtract one from the other to get a `TimeSpan` and then get its `TotalHours` property.  Save that value to a column of the appropriate type using a parameterised SQL statement.

Comment: @jmcilhinney tried that, doesn't work. Maybe I'm wrong in query but dunno what it is

Comment: Yes, you did it wrong. Edit your question to show what you did and explain what happened when you did it and we can tell you exactly what you did wrong.

Comment: @jmcilhinney any suggestions for a good title?

Answer (score 0):

So I'm wrong with the data type I used in database.

I used 
`[hours_work] DATETIME DEFAULT (NULL) NULL`
instead of `[hours_work] DECIMAL(18, 2) NULL`

So problem solved. Thank you @jmcilhinney for giving me the answer.
What I did on my `totalWorkHours` I changed it to double and still doesn't work. So I changed it back to string then tried changing the data type on my database. So thank you again :D